# SQL Substring after and before

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, substring

I am trying to find miss typed dates and i have this json in my query

> {"year":"2020","dateFrom":"2011-01-01T00:00:00Z","dateTo":"2011-12-31T00:00:00Z"}

1. Substring only the "dateFrom":"2011-01-01T00:00:00Z
2. Substring only the "dateTo":"2011-12-31T00:00:00Z
3. Validate that date are correctly typed

Comment: What actually is your question?

Comment: Why not parse the data as what it is, JSON, and then use `TRY_CONVERT`? As for fixing the data; that's for a person to do, not SQL. Then implement data validation in your application layer that inserts this data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the easiest method might be to parse the data as JSON, and then  use `TRY_CONVERT` to make sure it the date valid. Then you can manually fix the bad data:

```sql
SELECT J.Year,
       dateFrom,
       dateTo
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(YT.YourJson)
                 WITH (year int, 
                       dateFrom varchar(30),
                       dateTo varchar(30)) J
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),dateFrom,127) IS NULL
   OR TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),dateTo,127) IS NULL;
```